# Stream record containing large byte array from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, streaming, enterprise-library

I want to `stream` a record from SQL Server. The record contains a `byte` array (image) and metadata about the image. All I've seen so far is how to stream the column, *not the record*.

I have 2 questions:

- How can I stream the all data/record and populate my class?
- Why is `ExecuteSprocAccessor<>`, which I assume buffers, just as performant as the stream with a 65MB image (about 90 seconds)?

I inherited this code and think it's too slow and resource intensive, so I'm looking for alternatives and this makes the most sense, I think.

My attempt at streaming (it works):

```
System.IO.Stream stream;

using (var cmd = _mgr.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.uspUserDocument_Select", paramValues))
{
      cmd.Connection = _mgr.CreateConnection();
      cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;

      await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();

      using (var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess).ConfigureAwait(false))
      {
            while (await dr.ReadAsync())
            {
                 stream = dr.GetStream(4);
                 // I NEED TO GET THE WHOLE RECORD AND POPULATE A CLASS
            }
      }
}
```

Using `ExecuteSprocAccessor`:

```
return _mgr.ExecuteSprocAccessor<UserDocument>("dbo.uspUserDocument_Select",rowMapper, paramValues).ToList();
```

Comment: Alter the proc to accept parameters to filter down to the record you're interested in? Also, I know very little about it, but have you looked into `FILESTREAM`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Xedni...the proc returns 1 record with the byte[] and associated metadata.  The proc is a simple select statement

Comment: I'm a little confused then `All I've seen so far is how to stream the column, not the record`. I tend to think of the "record" as the "row", and if the proc returns 1 row, they're one and the same. Can you clarify what you're referring to?

Comment: @Xedni...it seems all the methods on the reader require an ordinal position, so you only get back that field, not the row - _dr.GetStream(4)_

Comment: The "row" is the combined set of all columns. So in the same way you can get the 4th column (ostensibly your byte field), so too can you get the rest of the record by referencing each column you care about. the internal state of the `SqlDataReader` (following the `dr.ReadAsync()`) *is* the row. You just interact with it's fields individually as needed.

Comment: @Xedni...okay, then I'd need to create a separate stream for each row and map to my object?  That doesn't seem right as in: dr.GetStream(3) , dr.GetStream(4) , dr.GetStream(5)

Comment: Technically, yes. Although you probably don't need to use `Stream` for the "normal" columns; you could just use `GetString()` or something similar. But fundamentally the concept is the same. You have to interact with each column/field in the row as it's own distinct thing.